# TreeView instead of WebView?

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

Once createTreeView() has created a TreeView instance, the reveal() takes your derived implementation of TreeItem. The reveal() does not take a ViewColumn as does the WebView[Panel]. The only way the vscode extension API can specify a ViewColumn is either a ExtHostTestEditor which implements the TextEditor interface, and the WebView. So do all custom editors have to be implemented with WebView? Are TreeView(s) only for activity bar side views?

It seems odd, since there is the admonition to not use WebView(s) since they are so heavy weight. Plus there is additional effort to make the WebView's look-and-feel match the editor. The [vscode-json-editor](https://github.com/sunmorgus/vscode-json-editor) uses a WebView and I haven't found any custom editors that do not use a WebView. Validating the WebView approach would help avoid going down a whole host of rabbit holes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

These types of views have different use cases. Here's a quick overview of each VS Code 1.28:

**TreeView**

TreeViews can be shown in the side bar, such as in the explorer or source control section. Tree views use a data driver api where VS Code controls the presentation. This means that you get a lot for free but that you cannot fully customize the behavior of a tree view.

Use a tree view if you want to add an additional data view. A good example of a tree view would be a custom file explorer, showing the outline of an editor, or presenting a list of resources.

**WebView**

Webviews can be shown in an editor. They can contain any sort of html content but you are entirely responsible for the user experience of this content.

Use a webview if you need a custom user experience or need to present a completely custom view of data.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. It would have been nice if the API and UI were more open to extension without using the WebView approach. Is the CSS exposed and importable to a WebView? If my WebView contains text, depending on how the CSS is written, the WebView HTML could reference the same CSS selectors.

Comment: No, you can't import VS Code's css into a webview. It's isolated, like a sandboxed iframe